# Trying to find maximum size of atomic load/store operation

Tags: c++, atomic

With below code

```
#include<atomic>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned char n>
struct AtomicTest
{
    char element[n];
};

template <>
struct AtomicTest<0>
{
    char element;
};

template<unsigned char i>
bool func()
{
    std::atomic<AtomicTest<i>> test;
    bool lf = test.is_lock_free();
    std::cout<<(int)i<<": "<<lf <<std::endl;

    if(i>0)
    {
        return func<i-1>();
    }
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    func<255>();
    return 0;
}
```

and VC++ setting in site https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual I get 8 bytes as maximum. When I try same on my pc with g++, I get this error:

> undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'

Is there another way of doing this so it doesn't generate this error for any compiler?

Comment: You need to compile with `-latomic`

Comment: Also not that `if(i>0)` should be `if constexpr(i>0)` otherwise you'll never stop instantiating `func`'s.

Comment: @NathanOliver  you find dup with the speed of light :)

Comment: @Oblivion Googling the error message brings it right up.

Comment: Ok thank you this worked @NathanOliver

Comment: @NathanOliver the question was up for just 6 seconds!

Comment: @Oblivion You must be experiencing some caching.  The Q was posted 11 minutes ago and I closed it 7 minutes later.